# Ruby module to print all method calls and returns in class

Tags: ruby, module

I'm trying to write on a module where it can be used on every class regardless of its content:

The module should perform the following:

- print the name method and its parameter whenever a method is called.
- print the return value of that method.

As an example I got:

```rb
class A
  extend Loginator

  def add(a, b)
    a + b
  end

  def sub(a, b)
    a - b
  end
  logify_me #this where the "logging happens!"
end


a = A.new
a.add(3, 5)
a.sub(7, 4)
```

output

```
Methode add(3, 5) called
returns 8
Methode sub(7, 4) called
returns 3
```

I don't know where to start from.
I already read the following links :

- [Difference between a class and a module / StackOverflow ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151505/difference-between-a-class-and-a-module?rq=1)
- [Writing Module for Ruby / StackOverflow ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548766/writing-module-for-ruby)
- [Ruby - Modules, and Mixins](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_modules.htm)
- [Ruby modules: Include vs Prepend vs Extend](https://medium.com/@leo_hetsch/ruby-modules-include-vs-prepend-vs-extend-f09837a5b073)
- [Modules in Ruby: Part I](https://medium.com/rubycademy/modules-in-ruby-part-i-a2cdfaccdb6e)

So what i did is the following but im kinda stuck:

## First try

```
module Loginator
  def logify_me(name)
    attr_reader name
    define_method("#{name}=") do |val|
      puts "#{name}=#{val}"
      instance_variable_set("@#{name}", val)
    end
  end
end

class Example
  extend Loginator
  logify_me :an_attribute
end

e = Example.new
e.an_attribute = 12
p e.an_attribute
```

problem with this code is that first i have to strictly write `logify_me` for each method and wont print anything if i wrote `logify_me` alone

## Second try

```
module Loginator
  def logify_me
    self.instance_methods.each do |method|
      define_method(method) do |*args|
        puts "Method #{method}(#{args.join(', ')})"
        puts "returns #{args}"
        args#problem this return the args not the results of each method?!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Note that i could use `TracePoint.trace(:call)` but its not what desired :).

Thanks for the user @pedrosfdcarneiro for pointing out the wrapper module
solution and providing this [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219277/how-do-i-wrap-the-invocation-of-a-ruby-method-by-including-a-module/23898539#23898539)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question isn't asked well. You gave us requirements, but didn't show us any attempt to solve the problem yourself. SO isn't a code-writing service, we help you debug code you wrote. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Comment: @theTinMan added where I'm currently at. so if you are planning to be helpful this is the right time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by defining a new wrapper method for each public instance method of the class that performs the log logic that you need.

```
module Loginator
  def logify_me
    self.public_instance_methods.each do |method|
      proxy = Module.new do
        define_method(method) do |*args|
          puts "Method #{method}(#{args.join(', ')}) called"
          # added join to match the exact desired output

          value = super *args

          puts "returns #{value}"

          value
        end
      end
      self.prepend proxy
    end
  end
end

class A
  extend Loginator

  def add(a, b)
    a + b
  end

  def sub(a, b)
    a - b
  end

  logify_me
end
```

Which yields the following output:

```
>> A.new.sub(1,2)
Method 'sub' called with args '[1, 2]'
returns -1
=> -1

>> A.new.add(4,7)
Method 'add' called with args '[4, 7]'
returns 11
=> 11
```

#### Explanation for the future :)

- `define_method(method)` :

  > Defines an instance method in the receiver. The method parameter can be a Proc, a Method, or an UnboundMethod object. If a block is specified, it is used as the method body. This block is evaluated using instance_eval [ref. can be found here](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/define_method)
- `prepend`

  > prepend will insert the module at the bottom of the chain, even before the class itself.[fourth ref on my post](https://medium.com/@leo_hetsch/ruby-modules-include-vs-prepend-vs-extend-f09837a5b073)

### Section to Edit by @pedrosfdcarneiro

please, add some brief explanation about the second inner module `proxy = Module.new do end` and why it's important for the return value and the usage of the super.

plus why did you preferred to use the `public_instance_methods` over `instance_methods`.

please kindly add some explanation about it because first its a bit unclear to me and secondly for the other noobs out there.
thanks in advance :)

This answer was heavily based on this fantastic answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23898539/1781212.

Comment: this works perfectly fine but would you please add some explanation about the usage of the `proxy = Module.new do end` and why its important for the return value. plus i kinda dont get the `super *args` so i would really appreciate it if you could add some explanation about those things for me as well for future people. thanks again :)